# auto identity field max value exceed status

Tags: t-sql

I am designin a new table which has an identity column with int type.The table supposed  to have inserts most than 500.000 daily .So how can i avoid  the problem  of identity field exceeding max value?
my sample table create snippet is below

```
CREATE TABLE IntegratorQueue(
        ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(0,1),--IDENTITY,
        RefDetailId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        RefStartDate datetime
        )
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GUID ( UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ) in your table as PK if you dont want to use BIGINT. The Max capacity of the GUID is 2^128.

```
CREATE TABLE IntegratorQueue(
        ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),--IDENTITY,
        RefDetailId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        RefStartDate datetime
        )
```

But if you need to know when will your INT identity exceed the max value you should check before the insert.

```
    INSERT INTO IntegratorQueue( RefDetailId, RefStartDate )
    VALUES ( NEWID(), GETUTCDATE() )

-- INT capacity (-2,147,483,648) to (2,147,483,647 ) 

    IF 2147483647 - SCOPE_IDENTITY() < 500000
    --... Do something... send an Email ( xp_sendmail. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260697(v=sql.80).aspx )
    -- Insert Notification records into an another table... 
    -- return with 1, or something else, like the end of your query instead of RETURN 0 RETURN 1 and check this... so on...
```

Maybe the DBCC CHECKIDENT( tablename, RESEED, currentseed+inserted)

Comment: yes DBCC CHECKIDENT is more  apporiate one to handle this i think....because the ID value will be used on UI also I preferred it to be int ..

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting more then 2^31-1. Then you can use `BIGINT` that is 2^63-1

```
CREATE TABLE IntegratorQueue(
        ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(0,1),--IDENTITY,
        RefDetailId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        RefStartDate datetime
        )
```

Comment: so one day it can be exceeded also...i 'm focusing to find answer   how to handle identity exceeded max value..

Comment: @dankyy1: How many items you plan to insert in the table pro second? You can calculate how many million years you need to wait till you `int` (2^31-1 = 2,147,483,647) or `bigint` (2^63-1 = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807) will be exceeded.

Comment: Even if you were inserting 1 million records a day, it would take 25 billion years to exceed the limits of BIGINT. This kind of future proofing is almost never required...

Comment: Your could drop the ID column and use RefDetailID as your primary key, this would allow for 5,316,911,983,139,663,491,615,228,241,121,400,000 different combinations.

Comment: @GarethD: It's what I mean too. I am even not sure that the developed program will be used *every day during the next 10 years* with daily insert of 500.000, but I agree that the usage of `bigint` will be better in the case. The exceeding of `bigint` is absolutely not realistic.

Comment: thanks for your answers guys..i know 10 year using a program is not a realistic target.but i want to think about worst case... also  isn't that using bigint instead of int take down  the query performance?